# Is there an equivalent word for "discourse" signifying not a way of speaking but a way of thinking?

Tags: single-word-requests

Normally "discourse" is used academically to describe the way a social group speaks about a particular subject. But is there an equivalent for how a social group thinks about that subject, even if it is not directly spoken about?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A belated _Hello_, Sarra. 'Normally "discourse" is used academically to describe the way a social group speaks about a particular subject.' There is normally an exchange of ideas, with people willing to be shown better analyses and approaches. // '[I]s there an equivalent for how a social group thinks about that subject' seems to be looking for a prevailing mindset. 'Discourse' is dynamic while 'how a group thinks about a subject' seems to be referencing a set stance.

Comment: The OP has failed to provide an example sentence. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Two words come to mind:

> *ideology*:
>
> a: a manner or the content of thinking characteristic of an individual, group, or culture.
>
> b: the integrated assertions, theories and aims that constitute a sociopolitical program.
> ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideology))

and

> *tenet*: a principle, belief, or doctrine generally held to be true
> *especially*: one held in common by members of an organization, movement, or profession ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenet))